# ML Gradle deploy search options with annotations issues

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

I am trying to deploy my search options with annotations and it gives me following error

```
Error caught while loading modules, cause: Local message: /config/query write failed: Bad Request. Server Message: RESTAPI-INVALIDCONTENT: (err:FOER0000) Invalid content: Operation results in invalid Options: XDMP-VALIDATENODECL: (err:XQDY0084) validate strict { $annotations } -- Missing element declaration: Expected declaration for node fn:doc("")/search:options/search:constraint[2]/search:custom/search:annotation/search:assays in non-lax mode using schema "search.xsd"fn:doc("")/search:options/search:constraint[2]/search:custom/search:annotation/search:assays"search.xsd"
com.marklogic.client.FailedRequestException: Local message: /config/query write failed: Bad Request. Server Message: RESTAPI-INVALIDCONTENT: (err:FOER0000) Invalid content: Operation results in invalid Options: XDMP-VALIDATENODECL: (err:XQDY0084) validate strict { $annotations } -- Missing element declaration: Expected declaration for node fn:doc("")/search:options/search:constraint[2]/search:custom/search:annotation/search:assays in non-lax mode using schema "search.xsd"fn:doc("")/search:options/search:constraint[2]/search:custom/search:annotation/search:assays"search.xsd"
```

But the same options work fine from query console.. when I looked up the `search.xsd` I don;t see anything different.. What am I doing wrong ?
Following is my options file

```xml
<options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
    <additional-query>
        <cts:and-query xmlns:cts="http://marklogic.com/cts">
            <cts:collection-query>
                <cts:uri>http://rdf.abbvienet.com/entity/abbvie/biologic</cts:uri>
            </cts:collection-query>
        </cts:and-query>
    </additional-query>
    <constraint name="target">
        <custom facet="false">
            <parse apply="parse-string"
                   ns="http://ir.abbvienet.com/pikm-datahub/custom-constraints/abbvie-biologic/abbvieBiologicTargetConstraint"
                   at="/lib/custom-constraints/abbvie-biologic/abbvieBiologicTargetConstraint.xqy"/>
        </custom>
    </constraint>

    <constraint name="documents">
        <custom facet="true">
            <parse apply="parse-string"
                   ns="http://ir.abbvienet.com/pikm-datahub/custom-constraints/abbvie-biologic/abbvieBiologicDadsELNConstraint"
                   at="/lib/custom-constraints/abbvie-biologic/abbvieBiologicDadsELNConstraint.xqy"/>
            <start-facet apply="start-facet"
                         ns="http://ir.abbvienet.com/pikm-datahub/custom-constraints/abbvie-biologic/abbvieBiologicDadsELNConstraint"
                         at="/lib/custom-constraints/abbvie-biologic/abbvieBiologicDadsELNConstraint.xqy"/>
            <finish-facet apply="finish-facet"
                          ns="http://ir.abbvienet.com/pikm-datahub/custom-constraints/abbvie-biologic/abbvieBiologicDadsELNConstraint"
                          at="/lib/custom-constraints/abbvie-biologic/abbvieBiologicDadsELNConstraint.xqy"/>
            <facet-option>frequency-order</facet-option>
            <facet-option>descending</facet-option>
            <facet-option>concurrent</facet-option>
            <annotation>
                <assays>
                    <assay label="Flow Cytometry">Flow Cytometry|FAC|Flow</assay>
                    <assay label="Immunohistochemistry">Immunohistochemistry|IHC</assay>
                    <assay label="Western Blot">Western Blot|Western</assay>
                    <assay label="Elisa">Elisa</assay>
                    <assay label="Binding Assay">Binding Assay|Biacore</assay>
                </assays>
            </annotation>
        </custom>
    </constraint>
    <term>
        <term-option>case-insensitive</term-option>
        <term-option>punctuation-insensitive</term-option>
        <term-option>whitespace-insensitive</term-option>
        <term-option>wildcarded</term-option>
    </term>
    <extract-document-data selected="include">
        <extract-path xmlns:ab="http://schemas.abbvienet.com/entity/abbvie/biologic">//ab:id</extract-path>
        <extract-path xmlns:ab="http://schemas.abbvienet.com/entity/abbvie/biologic">//ab:name</extract-path>
        <extract-path xmlns:ab="http://schemas.abbvienet.com/entity/abbvie/biologic">//ab:alternate-name</extract-path>
        <extract-path xmlns:ab="http://schemas.abbvienet.com/entity/abbvie/biologic">//ab:entity-type</extract-path>
        <extract-path xmlns:ab="http://schemas.abbvienet.com/entity/abbvie/biologic">//ab:entity-sub-type</extract-path>
        <extract-path xmlns:ab="http://schemas.abbvienet.com/entity/abbvie/biologic">//ab:scientist</extract-path>
        <extract-path xmlns:ab="http://schemas.abbvienet.com/entity/abbvie/biologic">//ab:registrar</extract-path>
        <extract-path xmlns:ab="http://schemas.abbvienet.com/entity/abbvie/biologic">//ab:project</extract-path>
        <extract-path xmlns:ab="http://schemas.abbvienet.com/entity/abbvie/biologic">//ab:isotype</extract-path>
        <extract-path xmlns:ab="http://schemas.abbvienet.com/entity/abbvie/biologic">//ab:species</extract-path>
        <extract-path xmlns:ab="http://schemas.abbvienet.com/entity/abbvie/biologic">//ab:comments</extract-path>
    </extract-document-data>
    <transform-results apply="empty-snippet"/>
</options>
```

When I remove the `<annotation>` tag from my second constraint, the options file gets deployed. When I look at the `search.xsd` I don;t see anything wrong with my `<annotation>` element ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's odd that the error message refers to search:annotation/search:region but the options don't show that element.

It might help to declare an empty default namespace on the annotation element as in:

```
<annotation xmlns="">
```

That way, the annotation subelements won't be in the search namespace and thus should never be validated against the search schema.

Comment: It still gives me the error 
`
 Local message: /config/query write failed: Bad Request. Server Message: RESTAPI-INVALIDCONTENT: (err:FOER0000) Invalid content: Operation results in invalid Options: XDMP-VALIDATEUNEXPECTED: (err:XQDY0027) validate strict { $opt } -- Invalid node: Found assays but expected (location*,infon*) at fn:doc("")/search:options/search:constraint[2]/search:custom/annotation/assays using schema "/annotations.xsd"assays(location*,infon*)fn:doc("")/search:options/search:constraint[2]/search:custom/annotation/assays"/annotations.xsd"
`

Comment: When I look at the `search.xsd` it does have the `annotation` element

Comment: I think when I added a prefix to the xmlns in your suggestion it worked..and not to the annotation but to the element underneath it

`<dads:assays xmlns:dads="http://pikm-hub-options.abbvienet.com">`